# iOS + Firebase - Send data from view controller to detail view controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a ViewController, where a list of data is being fetched from the `RealtimeDatabase` and being displayed in the `UITableView`. When a post is clicked, I want the data from the `ViewController` such as Title, Description, and Image to be carried forward into a DetailView i.e: `PostController.Swift` where I can further call more data from the `RealtimeDatabase` to be displayed in the `PostController.Swift`

I tried to use didSelectRowAt but was unable to fetch and display data in the PostController, I'm also currently trying to use prepare but getting stuck at the same place.

Here is the `ViewController.Swift`:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var tableView:UITableView!

    var posts = [Post]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .plain)
        view.addSubview(tableView)

        let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "PostTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "postCell")
        var layoutGuide:UILayoutGuide!

        layoutGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.reloadData()

        observePosts()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func observePosts() {
        let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("Data")

        postsRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            var tempPosts = [Post]()

            for child in snapshot.children{

                if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                    let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
                    let title = dict["title"] as? String,
                    let logoImage = dict["image"] as? String,
                    let url = URL(string:logoImage),
                    let description = dict["description"] as? String{


                    let userProfile = UserProfile(title: title, photoURL: url)
                    let post = Post(id: childSnapshot.key, title: userProfile, description: description, image: userProfile)
                    print(post)
                    tempPosts.append(post)
                }
            }

            self.posts = tempPosts
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

    func getImage(url: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> ()) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { data, response, error in
            if error == nil {
                completion(UIImage(data: data!)) 
            } else {
                completion(nil)
            }
            }.resume()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
        cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "PostDetailSegue" {


            if let indexPaths = self.tableView!.indexPathForSelectedRow{

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 let postsInfo = posts[indexPath.row]
 print(postsInfo)
 performSegueWithIdentifier("PostDetailSegue", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "PostDetailSegue" {
        if let indexPaths = posts[indexPath.row]{
     //add parmaters which passed to another viewcontroller   
     }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a reference to the `Post` in your `DetailViewController`.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "PostDetailSegue" {
        let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        detailViewController.setPost(post)

    }
}
```

And in your DetailViewController:

```
func detailViewController.setPost(_ post: Post) {
    // Store the post and fetch other data as necessary
    self.post = post
}
```

Comment: It gives an error, Value of type 'DetailViewController' has no member 'setPost', even after adding the func

Comment: I just used the example DetailViewController - you’ll need to add this function or equivalent to your detail controller.